# make objects appear in a flash

Tags: animation, objects, node-editor

I am making something in Blender. I was wondering if there were any way I could make 2 objects appear in a flash? What I mean is like a pulse that makes them appear. If not, can I make them appear in a glare? Please note these are two objects, and are not the only objects in the project.

Answer (score 4):

### Using Cycles materials

[image]

Create the appearing object with material that is **a combination of emitter and diffuse, and mix that with a transparent material**.

At the beginning of the animation the material should be completely transparent:

[image]
*Click the image to enlarge*

Animate the values for the emitter and the transparency so that as it becomes more visible it also becomes brighter with the emitter. Once it reaches the brightest value, start taking the emitter back to zero so that it becomes diffuse only with no transparency.

[image]
*Click the image to enlarge*

[image]
*Click the image to enlarge*

[image]
*Click the image to enlarge*

For added visual punch swich over to the compositor, where you can **add a glare effect** (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Filter > Glare*) to the whole thing.

[image]

---

### Using the compositor only

Separate the objects to appear in a **different render layer**.

[image]
*Click the image to enlarge*

Set the **alpha transparency** so that the layer is invisible at the beginning of the animation.

[image]
*Click the image to enlarge*

Then animate the values for the alpha channel so that the transparency is off and the layer is fully visible but very bright and blured.

[image]
*Click the image to enlarge*

Finally animate the values for the **brightness and blur** so that the render layer returns to its normal brightness and the blur disappears.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks great!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, the easiest way I have found is by animating the visibility.

*Step 1:* Go to the outliner (top left usually) and find the object (for me its Cube)
[image]

*Step 2:* Hover over the eyeball and camera and press "I"
[image]

*Step 3:* Go 1 frame ahead in the timeline (the frame you want it to disappear)
[image]

*Step 4:* Click both eye and camera off

[image]

*Step 5:* Hover over each eye and camera and again press "I" to set a keyframe.
[image]

Now the object will disappear, but you can do the opposite to make it appear in a flash.

I hope this helped! :)