# Using multiple glare filter nodes

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

How should I apply multiple glare filters to rendered frames of an animation? I have an object with an emission shader that is keyframed to glow brighter every now and then. I want it to have a small glare effect when it is glowing dimly, but have multiple more noticeable glare effects that will apply and stack on top of each other when it is glowing more brightly. However, just combining glare filters with different thresholds with an "add" node isn't working predictably. Please help!

Here is a GIF of a preliminary render I have.

https://gfycat.com/JollyUnconsciousInvisiblerail

I want the glare effect to glow extremely brightly for a second to hide the moment when the second line of text appears. (This is the title screen for a movie I am working on.)

How would I accomplish this while compositing? Please help!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42593/make-objects-appear-in-a-flash/42610#42610

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, specifically add images of your current node setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the "mix" function on the glare node. Just set it to 1 (outputs glare only) then add it back to the original with an add node, like this:

[image: composite node setup example]

Not only can you chain as many as you like this way, but you can use the factor on the add node to have complete control over the intensity of the effect.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly the effect I was looking for.