# 'Quantum Leap' effect in Blender VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

I was wondering if it was possible to replicate the famous Quantum Leap end of episode effect as replicated here: https://youtu.be/coUnhsJ3tUY ?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: In response to Firewill:

I think the three main features that I don't have a clue about how to implement are: 1) the 'electric current' that traverses the person's body, 2) the white 'filling-in' of the body shape, and 3) the blue light beams that come from behind the person during the 'leap'.

Comment: I know it probably isn't what you are asking but, yes, it is possible.
 It would be better if you asked a more specific question, what part of this effect are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @Firewill I think the three main features that I don't have a clue about how to implement are: 1) the electric current that traverses the person's body, 2) the white 'filling-in' of the body shape, and 3) the blue light beams that come from behind the person during the 'leap'.

Comment: You can use the VSE to make masks for the white glow effect, but the electricity and blue lines would have to be created in 3D scenes and added to the VSE (or better yet compositor). There are a number of steps so you would do best to pose each one as separate questions

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42593/make-objects-appear-in-a-flash/42610#42610 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/how-to-create-an-animated-electric-arc-or-lightning and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/using-mask-as-a-garbage-matte-to-hide-an-object